# Azure DevOps with self-hosted Ubuntu machine: docker fails

Tags: docker, ubuntu, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-pipeline

I created an Azure DevOps agents based on the Ubuntu image that can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation

After I deployed the machine and installed the agent (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=vsts) I ran a Docker task and got the following error:

> dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

What do I have to do to get the Docker task executed successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the agent service has not the permissions to connect. You can either run the agent service as root (`sudo ./svc.sh install root`) what I would not recommend or add the user to the Docker group via `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER`.

Then logout and and log in again and it should work.

See also https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: (But remember that anyone who can run any `docker` command can trivially get root on the system; guarding it behind `sudo` is not wrong.)